# Pandas calculate the time difference in seconds excluding business days

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time

I have a dataset that contains two columns. One is the `Message Received Timestamp` and another is the `Message Sent Timestamp`. The format of the time look like such `2021-06-05T07:00:34Z`. I would like to calculate the time difference in seconds between those two columns and make sure the difference is less than `24 hours` by excluding business days.

I am aware of the `np.busday_count` method but I would like to calculate the difference in seconds. Please see my current code below which fails to consider the business days: `(pd.to_datetime(df["Message Received Timestamp"]) - pd.to_datetime(df["Message Sent Timestamp"])) < pd.Timedelta("1 day")`

I would really appreciate your help to factor in the business days calculation (in seconds). Thank you so much.

Comment: that's quite easy to do... parse the values by hand and write your own output function

Comment: @Tartempion thanks for the suggestion but could you mind clarifying by parsing the values

Comment: sorry I misread something...

Comment: @Tartempion i was wondering if you could clarify what you meant by "parse the values"

Comment: I initially meant processing the strings to get the date and hour values, but pd.to_datetime seems to work just fine with your format

Comment: Just responded to the answer below, but in a quick summary, my current code does not exclude business days.

Comment: See my code that also exclude business days and get the total seconds simply by calling Pandas function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html) to get the total time difference in seconds between the 2 dates as follows:

```
df["Diff_Total_Seconds"] = (pd.to_datetime(df["Message Received Timestamp"]) - pd.to_datetime(df["Message Sent Timestamp"])).dt.total_seconds()
```

Then calculate the total seconds for business days by multiplying `np.busday_count` with 86400 (seconds in one day):

```
df["Busday_Total_Seconds"] = (np.busday_count(pd.to_datetime(df["Message Sent Timestamp"]).values.astype('datetime64[D]'), pd.to_datetime(df["Message Received Timestamp"]).values.astype('datetime64[D]')) - 1) * 86400
```

Finally, get the time difference in seconds excluding business days as their difference.

```
df["Diff_Total_Seconds_Excl_Busday"] = df["Diff_Total_Seconds"] - df["Busday_Total_Seconds"]
```

Test Result:

```
  Message Received Timestamp Message Sent Timestamp  Diff_Total_Seconds  Busday_Total_Seconds  Diff_Total_Seconds_Excl_Busday
0       2021-06-07T06:41:01Z   2021-06-04T07:00:34Z            258027.0                     0                        258027.0
1       2021-06-09T06:41:01Z   2021-06-08T07:00:34Z             85227.0                     0                         85227.0
```

### Edit

After further discussion with OP, we come up with updated codes with handling of some special cases.

```
df["Message Received Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Message Received Timestamp"])
df["Message Sent Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Message Sent Timestamp"])
df["Diff_Total_Sec"] = (df["Message Received Timestamp"] - df["Message Sent Timestamp"]).dt.total_seconds()
df["Diff_Days"] = (df["Message Received Timestamp"].dt.normalize() - df["Message Sent Timestamp"].dt.normalize()).dt.days
df["NonBDay_Total_Sec"] = (df["Diff_Days"] - np.busday_count(df["Message Sent Timestamp"].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), df["Message Received Timestamp"].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))) * 86400
df["NonBDay_Total_Sec"] = np.where((df["Message Received Timestamp"].dt.dayofweek == 6) & (df["NonBDay_Total_Sec"] < 86400 * 2), 86400 * 2, df["NonBDay_Total_Sec"])
df["NonBDay_Total_Sec"] = np.where((df["Message Received Timestamp"].dt.dayofweek == 5) & (df["NonBDay_Total_Sec"] < 86400), 86400, df["NonBDay_Total_Sec"])
df["Diff_Total_Sec_Excl_NonBDay"] = df["Diff_Total_Sec"] - df["NonBDay_Total_Sec"] 
df["Validity_Result"] = (df["Diff_Total_Sec_Excl_NonBDay"] < 86400) & (df["Message Sent Timestamp"] <= df["Message Received Timestamp"])
```

**Test Result:**

```
   Message Received Timestamp    Message Sent Timestamp  Diff_Total_Sec  Diff_Days  NonBDay_Total_Sec  Diff_Total_Sec_Excl_NonBDay  Validity_Result
0   2021-06-07 06:41:01+00:00 2021-06-04 07:00:34+00:00        258027.0          3             172800                      85227.0             True
1   2021-06-07 06:41:01+00:00 2021-06-07 05:41:01+00:00          3600.0          0                  0                       3600.0             True
2   2021-06-07 06:41:01+00:00 2021-06-07 07:41:01+00:00         -3600.0          0                  0                      -3600.0            False
3   2021-06-07 06:41:01+00:00 2021-06-03 06:41:01+00:00        345600.0          4             172800                     172800.0            False
4   2021-06-07 06:41:01+00:00 2021-06-10 06:41:01+00:00       -259200.0         -3                  0                    -259200.0            False
5   2021-06-07 06:41:01+00:00 2021-06-03 07:00:01+00:00        344460.0          4             172800                     171660.0            False
6   2021-06-07 06:41:01+00:00 2021-06-04 07:00:01+00:00        258060.0          3             172800                      85260.0             True
7   2021-06-07 06:41:01+00:00 2021-06-04 05:00:01+00:00        265260.0          3             172800                      92460.0            False
8   2021-06-06 22:01:03+00:00 2021-06-04 09:38:38+00:00        217345.0          2             172800                      44545.0             True
9   2021-06-05 07:01:36+00:00 2021-06-04 03:49:42+00:00         97914.0          1              86400                      11514.0             True
10  2021-06-07 01:10:09+00:00 2021-06-03 03:32:06+00:00        337083.0          4             172800                     164283.0            False
11  2021-06-06 09:03:34+00:00 2021-06-04 08:36:36+00:00        174418.0          2             172800                       1618.0             True
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion but for some reasons I will get this error `TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'`

Comment: @SkipperLin  Which line of code you got the error message ?

Comment: If I run the second line directly, I will have this error ```Could not convert object to NumPy datetime```. So I updated second line to become ```df["Busday_Total_Seconds"] = np.busday_count(pd.to_datetime(df["Message Received Timestamp"]), pd.to_datetime(df["Execution Timestamp"]))``` and I will get the error in my previous comment

Comment: @SkipperLin  Your Timestamp columns are probably strings and not datetime64 format then.   Ok, let me further check the 2nd line again.

Comment: thank you so so much! Yes the original format is strings and need additional casting.

Comment: @SkipperLin  See my edit above.  We need to convert the `datatime[ns]` object to `datetime[D]` object before passing to `np.busday_count`

Comment: That makes sense! Just to clarify, will the code identify ```date1 = '2021-06-04T07:00:34Z' ``` and ```date2 = '2021-06-07T06:41:01Z'``` as less than 1 business day? Because my concern is still with the second row: in those two above dates, the business day = 1 but the actual hours are 23 hours. We will be using 24 hours to do the calculation instead of 23.

Comment: @SkipperLin  Let's run it and see the result.  Let's see whether we need to adjust the number of business day by one day less or so.

Comment: @SkipperLin  Probably we need to swap the 2 parameter to the 2nd line, since the first parameter is the begin date and is supposed to be earlier date.

Comment: Hi @SeaBean, I think the parameter is fine because the dataset looks from the perspective of someone receiving the data. So the receive time should be later than sent time. I tried with ```date1 = '2021-06-04T07:00:34Z'```  and ```date2 = '2021-06-07T06:41:01Z'``` and it tells me that the gap is bigger than 1 day. The output was ```171627```

Comment: @SkipperLin  We should minus one day for the return result of `np.busday_count`.  I just updated the code above.

Comment: Minus one day will not work actually. Because for numpy, Friday and Monday is 1 business day. So if I minus one business day, it will actually generate an output of ```258027``` which was the value from the first line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233520/discussion-between-skipper-lin-and-seabean).

Comment: Hi @SeaBean, for some reasons, the code will identify the following records as failed but they should be correct under the weekend scenario we discussed. ```Message Received Timestamp Message Sent Timestamp
2021-06-20T00:37:10Z 2021-06-18T08:01:53Z
2021-06-20T00:44:25Z 2021-06-18T08:01:53Z
2021-06-20T00:47:43Z 2021-06-18T08:01:53Z
2021-06-20T00:20:04Z 2021-06-18T08:01:53Z
2021-06-20T00:25:37Z 2021-06-18T08:01:53Z
2021-06-20T00:48:09Z 2021-06-18T08:01:53Z
2021-06-20T00:28:03Z 2021-06-18T08:01:53Z
```